# How to merge two tables into a third table by giving the same primary key for matching records in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am not very professional with mysql. I am stuck with the following problem

I have 2 tables.

Table 1:

`ProjectName    Proj_Person     Year
Project1        John            2014
Project2        Sam             2014
Project3        Elizabeth       2014
Project4        Samuel          2014
Project1        John            2015
Project2        Sam             2015
Project3        Elizabeth       2015
Project4        Samuel          2015
Project1        John            2016
Project2        Sam             2016
Project3        Elizabeth       2016
Project4        Samuel          2016`

I assigned ID's for the above records in my 2nd table.

Table 2:

`Project_ID     ProjectName
PR00001         Project1
PR00002         Project2
PR00003         Project3
PR00004         Project4`

What I am trying to do now is, I want to merge both the tables so that I can have a final table (by keeping all the constraint intact on the final table) as

Table 3:

`Project_ID     ProjectName   Proj_Person   Year
PR00001         Project1        John        2014
PR00002         Project2        Sam         2014
PR00003         Project3        Elizabeth   2014
PR00004         Project4        Samuel      2014
PR00001         Project1        John        2015
PR00002         Project2        Sam         2015
PR00003         Project3        Elizabeth   2015
PR00004         Project4        Samuel      2015
PR00001         Project1        John        2016
PR00002         Project2        Sam         2016
PR00003         Project3        Elizabeth   2016
PR00004         Project4        Samuel      2016`

Request you to please help me with this problem. Any kind of help very much appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you use UNION

Comment: @Rasik I did make use of Union, but I am not getting the desired results in the third table. Also the third table should have Project_ID as the primary key column which I am getting it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you just need to join them on `ProjectName`:

```
select Project_ID, t2.ProjectName, Proj_Person, Year
from table2 t2
join table1 t1 on t2.ProjectName = t1.ProjectName
```

Comment: I need to dump all the records into the table 3 by combining the results from table 1 and table 2 along with the primary key constraint imposed on the third table

Comment: @Amrut what is the primary key constraint imposed on the third table?

Comment: it is an auto_increment column. Also as you can see that I want to put the same primary key for multiple records I am trying merge along with that. Like ` PR00001    Project1     John   2014
PR00001    Project1     John   2015
PR00001    Project1     John   2016`

Comment: I don't understand what you want beyond what's in this asnwer. The above query produces the output you want. If you want to actually insert this data into table3, put `insert into table3` in front of the above query, ie `insert into table3 select ...`. If you want something more than this. let me know, but please be very specific.